# parLapply takes a competely different amount of time inside and outside of a code

Tags: r, parallel-processing, timing

I have a running long code, where at some point I register a cluster of a few nodes and use parApply. I time the time it takes to execute this parallel calculation inside the code using `system.time`, save it to a variable and look at it after the code finished. Lets call it CalculationTimeInsideCode.

When I save the data frames and calculate the same piece of code outside the code (without restarting R or freeing memory!) - i.e., still in parallel but taking only the necessary lines from the code to run this part - the same line takes about 1/50 from what it took outside the code (lets call it CalculationTimeOutsideCode).

Is this related to other variables occupying the memory while running the code, that don't exist anymore outside the code?

The command I use for timing (in both cases) is:

```
system.time({result <- parLapply(cl, df , fun = SomeFunction)})
```

where `cl` is the registered cluster.

Comment: I think you need to provide a reproducible example of your issue.  Its impossible for us to know what the issue is without looking at the code in the two scenarios.  If you can't make it happen with example data, at least show us the code chunks  for each scenario and what is different between the two.

Comment: It is hard to provide an example because the code is long and produces many variables. But see my answer below

Comment: What does "outside the code" mean in this context? Not in parallel?

Comment: @Roman Lustrik See my edit

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have run some tests and found the answer to this question.
Apparently the exaggerated time is a result of many variables in the workspace, taking up a lot of RAM. When I remove the unnecessary variables, the code runs orders of magnitude faster. This was not intuitive to me.